# Bind attribute alternative for properties on complex types

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to bind a parameter X to a property called Y, I mean, the url parameter and the property name from the complex type are different.

How can I configure model binding so Y receives the value of X as the Bind attribute is not allowed on properties?

```
public class MyViewModel
{

[Bind(Prefix = "NameX")]
public String NameY { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample code of what have you tried?

Comment: Why is the url parameter different from the property name? Why don't you just simply change the property name to match the url parameter? Anyway, even if you could use the Bind attribute, it would not solve your problem. It would only work if your url paramter was like "NameX.NameY".